# fatal: not a git repository i am use git init then git status and it's work but then git add . not work

Tags: git, github

```
onep2@DesktopYoussef MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Documents/MyGithub/my-portfolio-website/potfolio
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Users/onep2/OneDrive/Documents/MyGithub/my-portfolio-website/potfolio/.git/

onep2@DesktopYoussef MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Documents/MyGithub/my-portfolio-website/potfolio (master)
$ git status
On branch master

No commits yet

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        css/
        images/
        index.html
        js/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

onep2@DesktopYoussef MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Documents/MyGithub/my-portfolio-website/potfolio (master)
$ git add .
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

onep2@DesktopYoussef MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Documents/MyGithub/my-portfolio-website/potfolio
```

i am trying to add files to my local repository but i faced this error the problem that the git status work but then like the git destroyed so what is the problem

Comment: Does it help if you change your directory and move out of the ~OneDrive folder to a local directory instead.?

Comment: thank u so much Rajat Gupta that's help me fix my issue

Comment: Posting this as an answer then!

Answer (score 0):

Moving the content to a local folder on Windows machine rather than a OneDrive directory should help fix this issue